# Response Surface Modeling and Optimization in Python: Analogous to rsm in R?

Tags: python, optimization, experimental-design, rsm

I wonder if there are modules in Python that support Design of Experiments, Response Surface Modeling and Optimization.  R has a number of libraries, such as rsm which helps you define a Design and then evolve it given outcomes to approach closer the optimum using the Response Surface Modeling approach, producing visualizations as well.  Still since I have begun using Python I would like to explore native possibilities to Python as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are.

1. Use [pyDOE](https://pypi.org/project/pyDOE2/) for experimental design; or [sobol_seq](https://pypi.org/project/sobol_seq/) to generate a sobol sequence
2. [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) regression algorithms for the response surface. Most response surfaces are ordinary least regression for a polynomial surface. They can be developed using Python as demonstrated [HERE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions).

The advantage here is that Python is completely free and there are loads of examples available as demonstrations on the internet.

Hope this helps.